# Can't plot ACS data in R

Tags: r, tmap

I would like to create a map of California using tmap, but I always get an error message

```
cmed<- get_acs(geography = "tract", variables = "B03002_003",
                state = "CA", geometry = TRUE, year = 2020)
cmed <- st_set_crs(cmed, 3490)
cmed <- st_transform(cmed,crs= 3490) 


tm_shape(cmed) + tm_fill("estimate")
```

and the error message is:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "SHAPE_AREAS", value = c(1.86607198659677e-11, : replacement has 9109 rows, data has 9129
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where does the `get_acs` function come from?

Comment: library(tidycensus)

Comment: Your transformation code is wrong. Did you not learn from the answer I gave you to a previous question? I do try and explain my answers rather than simply saying "do this" but if people won't learn then why do I bother?

Comment: but the last question, the code looks for me the same like this. but I study economics, maybe I don't know the difference, but I thought it is the same step.

Comment: Its the way you've assigned the CRS with st_set_crs, and then transformed to the same CRS. The data has the right CRS from `get_acs`, so you don't need to set it with `set_crs` - all that does it overwrites the correct CRS with a wrong one. Then the transform will do nothing because it thinks its already in your target CRS...

Comment: okay thanks, I just see, I did first on county level for Los Angeles and santa monica and so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additional warning message is more revealing from my point of view:

```
In addition: Warning message:
The shape cmed contains empty units.
```

```r
library(tidycensus)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(tmap)

cmed <- get_acs(geography = "tract", variables = "B03002_003",
                state = "CA", geometry = TRUE, year = 2020)

# as the warning says when running `st_set_crs()`:
# replacing crs does not reproject data; use `st_transform()` for that 

# your data is in epsg: 4269 natively, you overwrote this by epsg: 3490 before
st_crs(cmed)$epsg
#> [1] 4269

# that's how you actually reproject data using sf
cmed <- st_transform(cmed, crs = 3490) 

# 20 out of your 9129 geometries seem to be empty
st_is_empty(cmed) |> sum()
#> [1] 20

# filter your dataset for non-empty geometries
cmed_ne <- cmed[!st_is_empty(cmed), ]

tm_shape(cmed_ne) + tm_fill("estimate")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but I don't understand, why the shape of california is not in the right side by mine?

Comment: Could you elaborate what is wrong with the shape?

Comment: The first of those empty geometries appears to have a geometry, but its the eastern side of SF bay... https://censusreporter.org/profiles/14000US06001990000-census-tract-9900-alameda-ca/ I'm not surprised the population is zero but I don't know why the geometry is empty in the download though...